# Maneuver issues in Turn By Turn Navigation with HERE maps in Flutter

Tags: flutter, here-api, heremaps

Thanks in advance.

We have to use HERE map's Turn by turn navigation feature in one of our Flutter application, we have added billing in the developer account and have created the necessary keys.

When we try HERE map examples they have provided, we get everything except maneuver instructions that shows the user when to turn right/left/go straight for some distance etc.

I'm new to this and I have no idea how to get this, we never get events on the listener and it only shows updating there, am I missing something ?

[this is how it looks right now, Updating...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIiyd.png)

I think we should be getting the progress here, but we are not getting it here...
`_visualNavigator.routeProgressListener = Navigation.RouteProgressListener((routeProgress) { }`

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the provided example app. It shows [here](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/3ca4a7b4d58e87fdbe975424442cda26bfcf46f8/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/navigation_app/lib/NavigationExample.dart#L245) how to get the maneuver actions.

Your screenshot shows a different app, so make sure everything works with the example app, at first. The app offers to run a simulation mode. This should work. If you run the example app with real GPS updates, you may need to go outside and move to get location updates. This should also work.

If this still does not work, it could either mean that your device has an issue with getting GPS locations. Some iPads, for example, lack support. Or that you have disabled getting location updates. You can cross-check this when trying the [positioning_app](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/positioning_app) example from the same repository that shows how to get location updates.

A last point may be to clarify what events you get and what you miss: There are multiple event listeners providing real-time information during guidance - if you have only an issue with maneuvers, then most likely you can solve your issue by following strictly the code of the example app.

Note that previous HERE SDK versions, prior to HERE SDK 4.13.0, only provided empty maneuver instruction texts during guidance when they have been taken from the route instance. Make sure to take this information from the `VisualNavigator` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Nusatad, we have already tried what you instructed. However, it doesn't provide the proper solution, so we instead developed our own algorithms for turn-by-turn navigation and used OpenRouteService to get the routes. It is working properly right now. Thanks once again.